# "uptime" and "who" disagreeing

Tags: ubuntu, user-management, uptime

I've got an Ubuntu server that's exhibiting a somewhat strange behavior. `uptime` reports the following:

`07:48:10 up 627 days, 21:19,  3 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.01, 0.00`

`w` reports:

```
21:59:25 up 629 days, 11:30, 3 users, load average: 0.06, 0.10, 0.03
USER    TTY     FROM            LOGIN@  IDLE    JCPU    PCPU    WHAT
bedrick pts/8   c-67-171-191-108 21:59  0.00s   0.16s   0.00s   w
```

Note that it reports 3 users as being logged in. However, `who` and `last` both only show one user (myself). Any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: Try other commands like: "w" and "finger" and see the output.

Comment: This is `w`'s output:

Comment: 21:59:25 up 629 days, 11:30,  3 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.10, 0.03
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
bedrick  pts/8    c-67-171-191-108 21:59    0.00s  0.16s  0.00s w

Comment: Gah- the comment box mangled its output. The upshot is that it only shows the one login session (i.e., me) but still lists three users.

Comment: I'm more puzzled by the discrepancy in uptime.

Answer (score 3):

uptime shows you the number of sessions.  If you have X and two xterms open, you'll see three sessions.  who and last are being more discerning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. X isn't running on this system, actually- the only way to log in is via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Does `who` show three entries with your username? That's the three that `uptime` is reporting.

Comment: Nope, it just shows the one entry representing my SSH session.

Answer (score 1):

So you run top and your like uhhh... three users?

Type w. Typically you will see something like: gnome-session, bash, w.

This is expected. Gnome/KDE is your desktop environment. Bash is probably where your running "top" and w is the command you just executed... Cool huh?